# Change the color with the user option

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm working in my project with assembly emu8086 and I've done a lot of things:
[image]
Now I'm struggling to put the option selected by the user. I want to change the leds color from (0-7) using the user option, I've already done a lot of things I only dont understand how I'll do this to change the color, if the user select 1 both squares(leds) need to change to blue and this for all the colors, I need to verify the user option.

Here is my code:

```
title    ac-cores-mov-cursor.asm - desenha poligno colorido em modo texto
         org  100h           ; directiva para definição do enderço da 1ª instrução
; definição de constantes     

inicio:  jmp  princ          ; etiqueta e instrução de 'salto' para procedimento
  


;____________________Menu_cores___________________________
menucores    db   '1 black',0ah,0Dh
         db   '2 blue',0ah,0Dh
         db   '3 green',0ah,0Dh
         db   '4 cyan ',0ah,0Dh
         db   '5 red',0ah,0Dh
         db   '6 magenta',0ah,0Dh
         db   '7 brown',0ah,0Dh
         db   '8 light gray',0ah,0Dh  
         db "Please select a choice(1-8):",13,10,   '$'    
                                                   
                                                   
                                                   
                                                   
menu    db  '1 Todos os leds ligados',0ah,0Dh        ;leva ao menu cores para escolher a cor 
        db  '2 Combinaçao(0,2,4,6)',0ah,0Dh          ;leva ao menu cores para escolher a cor dos leds 0 2 4 6 
        db  '3 Combinaçao(1,3,5,7)',0ah,0Dh          ;leva ao menu cores para escolher a cor dos leds 1 3 5 7
        db "Please select a choice(1-8):",13,10,   '$'  
         
         
;____________________Menu_principal___________________________         
menuprincipal db   '1 Todos os leds desligados',0ah,0Dh   ; retorna os leds todos com a cor preta
              db   '2 Cor dos leds ',0ah,0Dh               ; leva para o menu cores
              db "Please select a choice(1-2):",13,10,   '$'      ;opçao escolhida
                                
                                
         
; definição de variáveis            
         
esqlin   db   15            ; linha do vértice superior esquerdo
esqcol   db   10              ; coluna do vértice superior esquerdo  


largura  db   2             ; largura do fundo
altura   db   2              ; altura do fundo   

texlin   db   17             ; linha do texto
texcol   db   12              ; coluna do texto 
colincio db   2
 
enter    db   0Ah,0Dh,'$'
fundo    db   'Cor fundo (0-9,A-F) ', '$'
texto    db   'Cor texto (0-9,A-F) ', '$'
corfund  db   0              ; 0-15 (decimal), 0-F (hexadecimal)
cortext  db   4             ; 0-15 (decimal), 0-F (hexadecimal)
frase1    db   'LED1', '$'  
corft    db   0Fh    

 



;___________________________START___________________________
verificacao:



princ    proc near           ; início do procedimento principal
         lea  dx, menucores      ; escrever string
         mov  ah, 09h 
         int  21h         
                  
                  
; define cor do texto e cor do fundo do ecrã         
         mov  corft, 24h  
         mov  bh, corft

         

                
         mov  ch, esqlin     ; vértice superior esquerdo - linha
         mov  cl, esqcol     ; vértice superior esquerdo - coluna
         mov  dh, esqlin         
         add  dh, altura     ; vértice inferior direito - linha 
         dec  dh
         mov  dl, esqcol     
         add  dl, largura    ; vértice inferior direito - coluna
         dec  dl 
         mov  ah, 06h         
         int  10h
                    
             

                

                     
                     
; instruções para terminar o programa
         mov  ax, 4c00h
         int  21h

princ    endp           ; fim do procedimento principal

; define cor do texto e cor do fundo do ecrã         
         mov  bh, 218        ; 218(16*13+10) = DAh: D - cor fundo, A - cor texto
         mov  al, 01h        ; nº linhas scroll
         mov  ch, 0          ; vértice superior esquerdo - linha
         mov  cl, 0          ; vértice superior esquerdo - coluna
         mov  dh, 0          ; vértice inferior direito - linha
         mov  dl, 46         ; vértice inferior direito - coluna
         mov  ah, 06h        ; scroll uma linha (al)=1
         int  10h

         mov  al, corfund
         mov  bh, 16         ; 16 = 2^4
         mov  ah, 0
         mul  bh             ; 16*corfund
         add  al, cortext    ; = corfund*16 + cortext
```

Comment: Well depends how you do the output. Usually in the DOS days you had two bytes per character. One for the ASCII and one for the color.  Example : you put ASCII to AL and Color to BL and then call INT10h. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H. If you need it more precise, please provide relevant code - so we can see how you are doing your output.

Comment: Here is my code:
we.tl/t-PRvhRsq3Sr
                  Is doing one green square and my objective is to do 7 squares(leds) like this in the same
line only incrementing the colum, for that i was thinking to do 7* my variables to 
use diferent numbers in colum but that is a masive code so  i'd like to find a 
better way to do this 7 leds in the same line.

Comment: "terminar o programa": I don't know spanish but the two lines below tells me that must mean "exit the program."
This might be the actual problem, you are facing: I think your trial code doesn't get executed.  See first you jump into the procedure(right at the start, line 3) put out the menu via dos, after that you actually set color but then you exit.
I think the remaining never gets executed and I think it does not even print the text led1 in wrong color - it doesn't print it at all.
Either move your code into the proc or jump after the proc and call it for output and put exit into main

Answer (score 1):

> I need to verify the user option.

Ask the user to press a key and verify if it was valid.

```
Again:
    mov ah, 00h    ; BIOS.GetKeyboardKey
    int 16h        ; -> AX
    cmp al, "0"
    jb  Again
    cmp al, "7"
    ja  Again
```

Here the user has made a valid selection from 0 to 7. Now turn this choice into a background color. Remember the input is still a character! Once converted, you put it into the high nibble of the attribute byte to be used for outputting to the screen.

```
    sub al, "0"    ; Convert from character to value (*)
    mov cl, 4
    shl al, cl     ; Shift into high nibble (background color)
    add al, 15     ; Add in low nibble (foreground color)
    mov bh, al
```

Your screenshot uses the red text color, but that would make the text disappear if the user selected the red backgroundcolor. That's why I suggest you use BrightWhite (15) as your foreground color.
(*) can be omitted in this particular case (because of the shift left that follows)

> I want to change the leds color from (0-7) using the user option,

The usual way would be to simply redraw the whole colored tile using the attribute set up in the `BH` register.

First you clear the tile using BIOS.ScrollWindowUp **with `AL=0` !**

```
    FirstButtonCol    db 10
    FirstButtonRow    db 15
    FirstButtonWidth  db 10
    FirstButtonHeight db 3
    frase1            db 'LED1', '$'

    ...

    mov  ch, FirstButtonRow
    mov  cl, FirstButtonCol
    mov  dh, ch
    add  dh, FirstButtonHeight
    dec  dh
    mov  dl, cl
    add  dl, FirstButtonWidth
    dec  dl 
    mov  ax, 0600h     ; BIOS.ScrollWindowUp AL=0
    int  10h
```

Then you position the cursor over the button and write the label "LED1"

```
    lea  si, [frase1]
    mov  cx, 1         ; ReplicationCount
    mov  bh, 0         ; DisplayPage
    mov  dl, FirstButtonCol
    mov  dh, FirstButtonRow
    add  dx, 0102h
NextChar:
    mov  ah, 02h       ; BIOS.SetCursor
    int  10h
    mov  al, [si]
    mov  ah, 0Ah       ; BIOS.WriteCharacter
    int  10h
    inc  dl            ; Next column
    inc  si            ; Next char
    cmp  byte [si], "$"
    jne  NextChar
```