# How to print matrix with int10h?

Tags: assembly, printing, draw, tasm, real-mode

Well as my question says, I need to print a matrix with the int10h but not just that, this matrix is of 0 and 1 where the 0 has to represent the color blue and the 1 the color red. So my question is how do I print this matrix and how do I make the be color blue and red be color red when printing? I am using TASM and can use either 16 or 32bit registers.
Here is an example:

```
oneMatrix db 00000000000
             00000110000
             00011110000
             00000110000
             00000110000
             00000110000
             00011111100
             00000000000
```

So as you can kind of see there, the 1 form a shape of a one. How do I print this using int 10h and where 0 is color blue and 1 is color red?

Comment: Do you want to do this in text or in graphics mode?  If in graphics mode, which mode would you like to use?

Comment: In graphics mode and the interruption 10 the mode any that works best for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute function 09h. Put either blue or red foregroundcolor in `BL` depending on the character at hand (read from the matrix).

```
    mov si, offset oneMatrix
    mov cx, 1    ; ReplicationCount
    mov bh, 0    ; DisplayPage
More:

    ... position the cursor where next character has to go

    lodsb
    mov bl, 01h  ; BlueOnBlack
    cmp al '0'
    je  Go
    mov bl, 04h  ; RedOnBlack
Go:
    mov ah, 09h  ; BIOS.WriteCharacterWithAttribute
    int 10h

    ... iterate as needed
```

Take a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611845/change-the-color-with-the-user-option/62626293#62626293). There's some similarity...

---

If you need the output to create a glyph on a graphics screen, then next code will help:

```
    mov  si, offset oneMatrix
    mov  bh, 0      ; DisplayPage

    mov  bp, 8      ; Height
    mov  dx, ...    ; UpperleftY
OuterLoop:

    mov  di, 11     ; Width
    mov  cx, ...    ; UpperleftX
InnerLoop:
    lodsb
    cmp al '0'
    mov al, 1      ; Blue
    je  Go
    mov al, 4      ; Red
Go:
    mov ah, 0Ch    ; BIOS.WritePixel
    int 10h
    inc cx         ; Next X
    dec di
    jnz InnerLoop

    inc dx         ; Next Y
    dec bp
    jnz OuterLoop
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it and let you know if this solved my problem

Comment: @DiegoEsquivel For the graphics screen you can use BIOS.WritePixel to create a character glyph from the data in the matrix. Edited my answer.